# Youtube Subscribtion Issue with android Data Youtube Api v3 Caused by: com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: NeedRemoteConsent

Tags: java, android, youtube-data-api

When I am trying to hit subscription with youtube channel id error occurred how to resolve this issue?

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException
```

2021-10-02 19:19:48.843 12033-12267/com.example.googlesignin W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:299)

```
Caused by: com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: NeedRemoteConsent
```

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Please obey to SO guidelines by not posting images of error messages but plain text.

Comment: Same issue occur,any solution?

Comment: no brother still im facing this issue